# Alamofire completion handler issue

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, alamofire

I have a POST request with certain data that I would like to receive. However when I use `responseArray` I would be thrown this error

> json data is nil

but when I use `responseJSON` everything would be fine. Why is this so?

This code does not work:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: parameters)
       .responseArray { (response: Response<[Particulars], NSError>) in

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)


            if let result = response.result.value
            {

                do{
                    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    realm.add(result, update: true)
                }

                catch let err as NSError {
                    print("Error with realm: " + err.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }
    }
```

But this is fine:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: parameters)
       .responseJSON { response in

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)


            if let result = response.result.value
            {

              print(result)

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }
    }
```

I need `responseArray` so that I can have `(response: Response<[Particulars], NSError>)` and store my JSON response into realm

**UPDATE**

This is the Particulars class that I want to connect to. I'm trying to map my JSON objects to Realm based on this article https://blog.hyphe.me/realm-and-alamofire-in-a-effective-harmony/

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper


class Particulars: Object, Mappable {
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var email = ""
dynamic var id = ""
dynamic var profilePicture = ""
dynamic var username = ""
dynamic var apiToken = ""


override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

//Impl. of Mappable protocol
required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id    <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    email <- map["email"]
    profilePicture <- map["profile_picture"]
    username <- map["username"]
    apiToken <- map["api_token"]
} 
}
```

And this is the JSON response:

```
[
  "name" : "Jonny Walker",
  "api_token" : "qwertyuiop1234567890",
  "profile_picture" : "http:default_profile_picture.jpg",
  "id" : 10,
  "email" : "jwalker@gmail.com",
  "username" : "jonny"
]
```

**UPDATE 2**

My completion handler is working fine with `responseObject` but my `realm.add xxx` is throwing up this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Object'

My code can be found here https://codeshare.io/v4M9M (lines 19- 25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alamofire page shows how to handle response and does not list the responseArray method. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-serialization

You can use the responseJSON to get the JSON and convert into an array that you want. It would look something like this, (make changes to this based on your JSON response)

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: parameters)
   .responseJSON { response in

        guard response.result.isSuccess else
        {
              //handle error 
              return
        }

        guard let value = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject], 
                           particularsArrayJson = value["particulars"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] 
        else{
               //Malformed JSON, handle this case
        }

        var particulars = [Particulars]()
        for particularsDict  in paricularsArrayJson{
              particulars.append(Pariculars(json:particularsDict))
        }
}
```

You have to have an initializer in your Particulars that will initialise from the JSON provided.

**Update:**

The realm add method takes an instance of a class which extends from Object
Object is a class provided by Realm. So you may have to read up the documentation more.

You should be doing this instead

```
      realm.add(particulars, updated:true)
```

Comment: Hi @Anirudh I know but based on this tutorial that I found online (see updated post) this is what they used (responseArray) also the reason I used Particulars is to connect to my Particulars class

Comment: Can you update the entire structure of your JSON?. Is your JSON an object containing the array of Particulars or just an array of particulars. i.e is the outer structure like {particualrs:[{name:"",api_token:""},{name:"",api_token:""}]} OR  [ {name:"",api_token:""},{name:"",api_token:""} ]

Comment: That's the entire JSON response.. It's an array of particulars. The thing is, I want to add my whole JSON response to realm

Comment: The JSON you have posted does not seem right. It has to be [{},{}] not [name:"",...]. When you mean you want to store the whole JSON, you want to store the plain JSON text into realm?. If so you can just get the JSON response as a string and store it. You do not need the responseArray call at all.

Comment: What I am looking for is to have data like the name and token passed into my realm database's name and token column. Does that mean I don't have to loop through the dictionary?

Comment: If you are getting the details of a single user try using responseObject. You will get the particulars object mapped. I think you are not clear about the JSON structure and the Mappable protocol you are using. Have a look at this link, you will know what to use https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: Yup I've tried that too but I was thrown an expected argument error (see updated post). Could you please help me this?